# Grid::Right align grid item

Tags: html, css, css-grid

By using the grid positioning of the buttons to the right. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <button>test 1</button>
    <button>test 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above scenario, how do I move the two buttons to the end of the parent div?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is.. you had set the grid width to 100px

Instead set column `width:100px` inside the grid, because grid is the container also use `justify-content:end;` to align the content to the right side.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
  justify-content: end;
}
 button{display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <button>test 1</button>
    <button>test 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Box_Alignment_in_CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: It seems  that :   with grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);   
 "justify-content:end"  doesn't work.  I just want to get an auto-width and align right, avoid hard-coding width of items. what's the workaround?

Answer (score 4):

Hope this is helpful for you!

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto; //added
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <button>test 1</button>
    <button>test 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

use `justify-content: end;` & `grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;`

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
  justify-content: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <button>test 1</button>
    <button>test 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `margin:auto` for this:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  margin-left:auto;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <button>test 1</button>
    <button>test 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```